# How to calculate the value of a column plus the value of the next column with MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate the  value of a column plus the value of the next column with MySQL like that :

```
date   | 01-09-2014 | 01-10-2014 | 01-11-2014
A      |        2.0 |        5.0 |        3.0
B      |        2.0 |        7.0 |       10.0
```

Comment: Which columns did you want to sum up? What results are you expecting? Really - we can't read your mind. Despite what the old gypsy woman may have said, the cards do not foretell all. The Oracle at Delphi has been out of the office for some time now so we can't ask her (and anyways, I'm not big on snakes). Prophets are typically badly-dressed and smelly - NOT the kind of guys I want to ask for a read on the past, present, or future! So, basically, a bit more information added to your question would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

select columnA + ColumnB as SumOf from your_table.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your column name as `A` and `B`

The query should look like

```
SELECT A+B FROM yourtable
```